# XAMARIN: I have two labels inside my Listview, I need to get their text in .cs but I cant access them through x:Name

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

This is my .xml file - part of listview, where the labels get the data from API. When I click one item I need to get its value of Title and/or Date.

```
ListView x:Name="listViewStories" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label x:Name="titleOfStory" 
                                Text="{Binding Title}" 
                                   TextColor="Black"
                                   FontSize="20"
                                   WidthRequest="180">
                            </Label>
                            <Label x:Name="dateOfStory" 
                                Text="{Binding Date}" 
                                   TextColor="Black"
                                   FontSize="20"
                                   WidthRequest="180"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

and this is my .cs file which I used just as an example the DisplayAlert code so I can get the value, I tried different methods but I couldn't find a solution:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ReadYourPastPage : ContentPage
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    string _ID;

    public ReadYourPastPage(string id)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _ID = id;
        GetStories();


        listViewStories.ItemTapped += ListViewStories_ItemTapped;
    }

    private void ListViewStories_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayAlert("I need here to show Title or Date ->", e.Item.ToString() , "Cancel");
    }

    public async void GetStories()
    {
        var response = await client.GetStringAsync(returnJSON.GetURL() +
            "index.php?IDuser=" + _ID +
            "&getStories");

        var stories = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Story>>(response);
        listViewStories.ItemsSource = stories;
    }
}
```

Comment: please do NOT post code as images.

Comment: Welcome! It will be easier for people to help if you post your code as text in the question (and make sure it's formatted as code), not as an image that people need to spend extra time transcribing.

Comment: I edited it, thank you! And sorry about it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ItemTapped` and `ItemSelected` events give you back the **Binding Context** associated with the current Listview Cell. I would suggest using the `ItemSelected` event instead of the `ItemTapped`. In the event you can use the below code to get your object:

```
private void ListViewStories_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // This line null checks the object and also gives you a reference
    if (e.SelectedItem is Story story)
    {
        DisplayAlert($"Title -> {story.Title}   Date -> {story.Date}", "Cancel");

        // Deselect the cell that was tapped
        listViewStories.SelectedItem = null;
    }
}
```

You can't reference the `ViewCell` in your .cs code behind. You can only access the **Binding Context**

Comment: Thank you so much! Been trying to solve this for few hours. You're a life saver! Thank you.